# Bacula libs3 make show compiling error 127

Tags: makefile, backup, gnu-make, bacula

I am testing various backup tools in my company, and currently I am in the process of configuring and installing Bacula on Ubuntu server 21.10.

I have successfully installed bacula, checked the status of the services and they are all correctly running.
Reading from the bacula release note documentation, to perform backups on Cloud S3 it is necessary to install the libs3 library.

On the Bacula site there are therefore the installation instructions, I then downloaded the file `libs3-20200523tar.gz`, unzipped.
So I go into the folder with `cd libs3-20200523` and run the `make` command.

When I run the command I get the following error (I attach screen), and analyzing the GNUmakefile at line 225 I cannot understand what the error (the second screen) depends on (this is the first time I have encountered problems of this type).

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

- make error:
  [image: libs3 make error]
- GNUmakefile:
  [image: GNUmakefile]

EDIT ( Solution to my problem )

After installing `gcc` on the server as suggested by MadScientist there were still some problems, which I then solved and I hope the solution will be of help to other users.

Solution:
The problem, once fixed the gcc was caused by the path where I was going to run the `make` command, this because in the description of the installation present in the Bacula release notes, the correct path was not specified.
In fact, once the `liba3-20200523.tar.gz` file has been unpacked it must be moved to `/ usr / src / libs3-20200523` so at this point give the commands `make` and `make install`.
I found the solution from a Bacula Latino America webinar, I am attaching the link:

[Bacula libs3 installation webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJvTf2d3ad4)

Comment: Please do not use screenshots in StackOverflow.  They are hard for some people to read, they can't be searched, and they can't be copied for cut and paste.  Instead, edit your question and cut and paste the text into the question with proper formatting applied.

Comment: The error message is _cc: no such file or directory_.  `cc` is the C compiler.  You can't compile C code without a C compiler, and you don't have one.  You should install it onto your system.  On Ubuntu, you should use something like `sudo apt-get install gcc` to install a C compiler.